# RemoveAll method in a Double Linked List?

Tags: java, removeall

How would you implement a RemoveAll method for a Double Linked List? I have a normal remove method:

```
public boolean remove(String s){
    //lists is empty
    if(head==null){
        return false;
    }

    //list has 1 element and we want to remove it
    if(head.getData().equals(s) && head==tail){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        return true;
    }

    //s is at the front of the list
    if(head.getData().equals(s)){
        head = head.getNext();
        head.setPrev(null);
        return true;
    }

    MyDoublyNode currentNode = head;
    while(currentNode.getNext()!=null && 
          !currentNode.getNext().getData().equals(s)){
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }

    //we never found it
    if(currentNode.getNext()==null){
        return false;
    }

    //trying to remove the tail
    if(currentNode.getNext().getData().equals(s) &&
       currentNode.getNext() == tail){
           currentNode.setNext(null);
           tail = currentNode;
           return true;
    }

    //we've found what we're trying to remove, remove it
    if(currentNode.getNext().getData().equals(s)){
        currentNode.getNext().getNext().setPrev(currentNode);
        currentNode.setNext(currentNode.getNext().getNext());
        return true;
    }

    //never found s, return false
    return false;
}
```

I want to cut out a value with one swoop without having to use a statement calling remove more than I need to. I am not completely familiar with Nodes and Double Linked Lists yet.

Comment: try to use clear(); or .reset();